# Replacing values in the array nvp

Tags: php

I have been trying to replace the values in the array
I'll name this array as $currencies when i print this it looks like.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [currencylabel] => USA, Dollars
        [currencycode] => USD
        [currencysymbol] => $
        [curid] => 1
        [curname] => curname1
        [check_value] => 
        [curvalue] => 0
        [conversionrate] => 1
        [is_basecurrency] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [currencylabel] => India, Rupees
        [currencycode] => INR
        [currencysymbol] => ₨
        [curid] => 2
        [curname] => curname2
        [check_value] => 
        [curvalue] => 0
        [conversionrate] => 50
        [is_basecurrency] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [currencylabel] => Zimbabwe Dollars
        [currencycode] => ZWD
        [currencysymbol] => Z$
        [curid] => 3
        [curname] => curname3
        [check_value] => 
        [curvalue] => 0
        [conversionrate] => 22
        [is_basecurrency] => 
    )
```

)

Here I am having a $conversionRate to which i need to divide the values present in the array $currencies [0] -> Array -> [conversionrate] and replace in the same place in array.
and the same operation for [1] -> Array -> [conversionrate] and so on..
for which my current approach is as follows

```
$conversionRate = 50;
    foreach ($currencies as $key => $val) {
        $key['conversionrate'] = $key['conversionrate'] / $conversionRate;
        if($key['conversionrate'] == 1) {
            $key['is_basecurrency'] = 1;
        }  else {
            $key['is_basecurrency'] = '';
        }
    }
    print_r($key);
    die;
```

Currently this is not working kindly help

Comment: it is throwing an error when get's inside the foreach loop on the very first line..

Comment: Why it is tagged with `java,c++,c`?

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is all wrong, there is no $key['conversionrate'], it's $val['conversionrate']. In fact there doesn't seems to be a reason for the $key variable, you can just loop through the array with

```
foreach ($currencies as &$val)
```

Also, you probably want to print_r($currencies), not $key

Answer (score 1):

Do not compare floating point numbers with == to 1, it might not work due to rounding errors.

You mixed up key and value and you need to use &$val to be able to change the array.

```
$conversionRate = 4;
foreach ($currencies as $key => &$val) {
    if($val['conversionrate'] == $conversionRate) {
        $val['is_basecurrency'] = 1;
    }  else {
        $val['is_basecurrency'] = '';
    }
    $val['conversionrate'] = $val['conversionrate'] / $conversionRate;
}
unset($val);
print_r($currencies);
die;
```

Comment: Need is a big word, could also do $currencies[$key]

Comment: No, It is giving me the Just the final set of values
   [currencylabel] => Zimbabwe Dollars
        [currencycode] => ZWD
        [currencysymbol] => Z$
        [curid] => 3
        [curname] => curname3
        [check_value] => 
        [curvalue] => 0
        [conversionrate] => 22
        [is_basecurrency] => 
The Rest of the array elements have been off..

Comment: I don't get what you want as a result then. Zimbabwe Dollars is your base currency? Did you add the `&` in `foreach ($currencies as $key => &$val)` ?

Answer (score 0):

$key is an index identofoer of an array and $val contain array values

so use like this

```
$conversionRate = 4;
    foreach ($currencies as $key => $val) {
        $val['conversionrate'] = $val['conversionrate'] / $conversionRate;
        if($val['conversionrate'] == 1) {
            $val['is_basecurrency'] = 1;
        }  else {
            $val['is_basecurrency'] = '';
        }
    }
    print_r($val);
    die;
```